# What is that manga about an elf who made swords out of his hair?

Tags: ubel-blatt

This manga had a kind of small elf, and he had multiple swords that he could make out of his hair, and the bad guys were looking for him. The manga starts out with him being knocked out and a little girl/boy feeds him and he wakes up. Please help identify it, I really want to finish reading it!

Comment: Is it a little boy and a little girl or someone who you aren't sure if they are a boy or a girl?

Comment: Im not sure its been a while

Comment: He might have a scar over one eye too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's **[Übel Blatt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbel_Blatt)**.

> The story of Übel Blatt takes place in a medieval, fantasy-like landscape. It follows the steps of Koinzell, who appears to be nothing more than a mere half human child most distinguishable for the scar over his left eye. He is on a quest of revenge against those who betrayed and killed him and now call themselves the seven heroes of the land.
>
> Beginning some twenty years prior to the start of the manga, the story narrates on how Koinzell, then named Ascheriit, was a young, prodigious swordsman whose skill granted him the fabled title of Blatt Meister (literally Blade Master). His deeds made him one of the fourteen chosen by the ruling emperor of the Empire of Szaalenden to venture into a dangerous quest to defeat a powerful enemy invader known as the evil nation of Wischtech, of whom the many powerful engines of destruction and dark sorceries made a dangerous foe. Each armed with a lance blessed by the Emperor himself, and thus known as the Fourteen Lances, the chosen traveled far into the enemy's wasted landscape, losing three of their ranks to the perils of the land, until they arrived into a forest where seven of the eleven remaining decided to forfeit their mission, fearing for their lives. Nevertheless, Ascheriit and three of those still bent on following the Emperor's will continued, and incredibly succeeded in their deed, returning victorious. It was then that the seven who were left behind ambushed their comrades and massacred them. Back home, they told the Emperor that the four they killed turned traitors against them, and after dispatching them the seven completed the task. Thus, they were hailed as heroes and dubbed the Seven Heroes, while the four who were killed became symbols of treachery and received the spregiative moniker of Lances of Betrayal.
>   
>   Thus, the story tells of the voyage of Ascheriit, who indeed survived the slaughter and vowed to take the head of his traitorous companions, now powerful nobles and warlords hailed as saviors by the people.

[image: A Nice Übel Blatt Pic]

Comment: @Krazer I *think* there's a 48 hour wait time to self-accept.